# Memory leak in Camel netty TCP client when consuming lines with Windows line breaks (CR LF)

Tags: memory-leaks, apache-camel, netty

My Camel netty tcp client consuming text lines seems to have a memory leak but only if the test data lines end with Windows (CR LF) line breaks. I encountered no issues with Unix (LF) line breaks.

I made a short test to demonstrate the issue simulating a tcp server continuously sending test data lines.

With Unix (LF) line breaks in test data I see a throughput of about 3.500 messages/second and steady 180 MB ram use. No issues.

With Windows (CR LF) line breaks in test data I see a throughput starting with 380.000 (woah!) messages/second until hitting my -Xmx4G heap limit after about 30 seconds and slowing down considerably probably because of excessive GC; if given more heap it grows steadily until hitting that limit (tried with -Xmx20G).

The only difference is really the line breaks in my test data... 
Am I missing something here?

Using Camel 2.24.0 (which is using netty 4.1.32-Final) on Linux with OpenJDK 1.8.0_192. The problem also occurs with latest netty 4.1.36.Final. Also occurs with OpenJ9 JVM, so does not seem to be JVM specific.

```
public abstract class MyRouteBuilderTestBase extends CamelTestSupport {
    private final int nettyPort = AvailablePortFinder.getNextAvailable();

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("netty4:tcp://localhost:" + nettyPort + "?clientMode=true&textline=true&sync=false")
                    .to("log:throughput?level=INFO&groupInterval=10000&groupActiveOnly=false");
            }
        };
    }

    protected void startServerStub(String testdata) throws Exception {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(nettyPort);
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        for (;;) {
            out.print(testdata);
        }
    }

    @After
    public void after() throws Exception {
        if (out != null) out.close();
        if (clientSocket != null) clientSocket.close();
        if (serverSocket != null) serverSocket.close();
    }
}

public class MyRouteBuilderTestUnixLineBreaks extends MyRouteBuilderTestBase {
    @Test
    public void testUnixLineBreaks() throws Exception {
        startServerStub("my test data\n");  // Unix LF
    }
}

public class MyRouteBuilderTestWindowsLineBreaks extends MyRouteBuilderTestBase {
    @Test
    public void testWindowsLineBreaks() throws Exception {
        startServerStub("my test data\r\n");  // Windows CR LF
    }
}
```

Comment: Try look at the textline codec from Netty, and its docs, there may be something about you need to setup which kind of line breaks to use etc.

Answer (score 4):

Heap dump analysis showed that the memory is getting allocated by one instance of *io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor* which is using a *LinkedBlockingQueue* with unlimited size internally. This queue grows indefinitely under load causing the issue.

The *DefaultEventExecutor* is created by Camel because of the parameter **usingExecutorService** which is true by default (maybe not a good choice). Setting **usingExecutorService=false** makes Netty use its event loop instead of the executor which works much better.

I now get **600.000 messages per second throughput** with data using Windows line breaks (CR NL) with a steady ram use of about 200mb (-Xmx500M). Nice.

Though with data using Unix line breaks (NL) the throughput is  only at about 6.500 messages per second, two orders of magnitude slower, which was still puzzling.

The reason is that Camel creates its own *org.apache.camel.component.netty4.codec.DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder* class by subclassing Netty's *io.netty.handler.codec.DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder* -- I don't know why since Camel's class does not add any functionality. But by subclassing, Camel prevents a certain optimization inside Netty's *DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder* which switches to *io.netty.handler.codec.LineBasedFrameDecoder* internally, but only if not subclassed.

To overcome this I needed to explicitly declare decoder and encoders using Netty's classes instead, in addition to setting usingExecutorService=false.

Now I get the 600.000 messages per second throughput with data using Unix line breaks (NL) too and see a steady ram use of about 200mb. That looks much better.

```
public abstract class MyRouteBuilderTestBase extends CamelTestSupport {
    private final int nettyPort = AvailablePortFinder.getNextAvailable();

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;

    @Override
    protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
        JndiRegistry registry = super.createRegistry();

        List<ChannelHandler> decoders = new ArrayList<>();
        DefaultChannelHandlerFactory decoderTextLine = new DefaultChannelHandlerFactory() {
            @Override
            public ChannelHandler newChannelHandler() {
                return new io.netty.handler.codec.DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(1024, true, Delimiters.lineDelimiter());
                // Works too:
                // return new LineBasedFrameDecoder(1024, true, true);
            }
        };
        decoders.add(decoderTextLine);
        ShareableChannelHandlerFactory decoderStr = new ShareableChannelHandlerFactory(new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.US_ASCII));
        decoders.add(decoderStr);
        registry.bind("decoders", decoders);

        List<ChannelHandler> encoders = new ArrayList<>();
        ShareableChannelHandlerFactory encoderStr = new ShareableChannelHandlerFactory(new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.US_ASCII));
        encoders.add(encoderStr);
        registry.bind("encoders", encoders);

        return registry;
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("netty4:tcp://localhost:" + nettyPort + "?clientMode=true&textline=true&sync=false&usingExecutorService=false&encoders=#encoders&decoders=#decoders")
                .to("log:throughput?level=INFO&groupInterval=10000&groupActiveOnly=false");
            }
        };
    }

    protected void startServerStub(String testdata) throws Exception {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(nettyPort);
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        for (;;) {
            out.print(testdata);
        }
    }

    @After
    public void after() throws Exception {
        if (out != null) out.close();
        if (clientSocket != null) clientSocket.close();
        if (serverSocket != null) serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

**Update**: The memory usage issue is not a memory leak (and I regret phrasing my question that way) but about buffering. Please consult comments to this answer by users Bedla and Claus Ibsen to get a good understanding of the consequences of the solution outlined above. Please also consult [CAMEL-13527](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13527)

Comment: `I don't know why since Camel's class does not add any functionality.`. This delegation is there because Camel needs access to method`DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder#decode`, which is protected. But you are right, this skips some useful optimisations inside original netty codec. I am working on improvement [CAMEL-13527](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13527)

Comment: Just mind that using the event loop of Netty works great when you process the messages without any kind of potentially thread blocking, so the option in camel-netty4 with the thread pool is to be conservative.